# How to annotate a final id field with @Id annotation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, annotations, repository, spring-mongodb

Is it possible to annotate a field id with @Id annotation in Spring if this field is final? Ok, the story is that if I remove final field for id and I try to save it in database (in my case is mongodb) it works without any problem even if I left this field null it is anyway generating automatically but with final it throws a NullPointerException if I do not fill it. I would like to keep the entity implementation that you can see a little below.

Thanks for any help in advance, with best regards Victor.

```
@Document(collection = "posts")
public class PostEntity {
    private final String id;
    private final String title;
    private final String content;
    private final Instant createTime;
    private final Instant updateTime;
    private final Instant deleteTime;
    private final PostTypeEnum postType;

    private PostEntity(Builder builder) {
        this.id = builder.id;
        this.title = builder.title;
        this.content = builder.content;
        this.createTime = builder.createTime;
        this.updateTime = builder.updateTime;
        this.deleteTime = builder.deleteTime;
        this.postType = builder.postType;
    }

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public Instant getCreateTime() {
        return createTime;
    }

    public Instant getUpdateTime() {
        return updateTime;
    }

    public Instant getDeleteTime() {
        return deleteTime;
    }

    public PostTypeEnum getPostType() {
        return postType;
    }

    public static final class Builder {
        private String id;
        private String title;
        private String content;
        private Instant createTime;
        private Instant updateTime;
        private Instant deleteTime;
        private PostTypeEnum postType;

        private Builder() {
        }

        public PostEntity build() {
            return new PostEntity(this);
        }

        public Builder id(String id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder title(String title) {
            this.title = title;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder content(String content) {
            this.content = content;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder createTime(Instant createTime) {
            this.createTime = createTime;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder updateTime(Instant updateTime) {
            this.updateTime = updateTime;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder deleteTime(Instant deleteTime) {
            this.deleteTime = deleteTime;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder postType(PostTypeEnum postType) {
            this.postType = postType;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the behavior described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57682312/1823545 ?

Comment: Thanks for reference, as I understand correctly just shortly speaking the id property as a final is for manual id generating and non final for generating it automatically.

Comment: Assigning a value to `@Id` field has it's consequences. Regardless of this field being final or not. The `@Id` field is by default used to recognize *completely new* and *existing* entities.

You may consider having two fields: `@Id` (long) that is generated by DB and some other field (UUID) that you fill in JAVA.