# Approach for high number of persist/merge with saveAll JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In my application I received everyday millions of records, I split in Lists of 200 items.

Actually I'm using `saveAll()` with batch setup:

```
        order_inserts: true
        order_updates: true
        batch_versioned_data: true
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 20
```

My entity has a compound primary key `@EmbeddedId` composed by 5 fields from the record.

Actually with no `@Version`:

```
    @LoggingOff
    public void createAll(List<MyEntity> myList) {
        repository.saveAll(myList);
    }
```

So the application is always performing a `SELECT` and then an `UPDATE` this is causing a very poor performance.

Then I started to try to perform `persist()` when is a new one and `merge()` when is a existing record.

So I tried some options:

1. Use Persistable to mark an entity as new or not new as described here: [Oliver Persistable Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57682312/8107849)

It works, but I'm still relying in something to check if the PK exists (I created a POC relying on Redis), but in my case Redis is temporary so isn't an option for my case.

2. I also tried with the option described on the book `Spring Boot Persistence Best Practices` the `saveInBatch` approach.

```
    public <S extends T> void saveInBatch(Iterable<S> entities) {

        if (entities == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The given Iterable of entities not be null!");
        }

        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();

        try {
            entityTransaction.begin();

            int i = 0;
            for (S entity : entities) {
                if (i % batchSize == 0 && i > 0) {
                    logger.log(Level.INFO,
                            "Flushing the EntityManager containing {0} entities ...", batchSize);

                    entityTransaction.commit();
                    entityTransaction.begin();

                    entityManager.clear();
                }

                entityManager.persist(entity);

                i++;
            }

            logger.log(Level.INFO,
                    "Flushing the remaining entities ...");

            entityTransaction.commit();

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (entityTransaction.isActive()) {
                entityTransaction.rollback();
            }

            throw e;
        } finally {
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }
```

It works, but the problem still the same because the saveInBatch is using always `persist()`.

So I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '2021-08-31-1234-XXX-5678-2021-09-08' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

How could I handle merge and persist with saveAll method?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think this question ought to be on Code Review

Comment: @ControlAltDel https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ this one?

Comment: Yes that one. I think Code Review is more suitable for your question

Comment: @ControlAltDel I agree that this post appears off-topic for SO however it doesn't appear to have enough code for CR - please refer to [this meta post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652).

Comment: @GuilhermeBernardi if you post on Code Review please read the help center pages like [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - in its current form this post would be considered off-topic because there is very little actual code to review

Comment: @ControlAltDel and SAM I agree with both of you, but isn't only a code for review, because I'm still with the problem. SaveAll doesn't work for what I need, maybe the question isn't following the patterns only.

Comment: I'd give it a shot. Post what you've tried (including code/configurations/etc) and see how it goes. If it doesn't go well, I recommend you then go to meta.stackoverflow.com and ask about how to proceed there.